# Menu items change their positions in html/css menu when expanding submenu

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu made in html/css and the problem I encountered is that if I put my mouse pointer over menu item (test2) to expand submenu then other items from menu section (test1) change their positions: https://jsfiddle.net/dsb87pxz/

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>
      test2
      <ul>
        <li>test2.1</li>
        <li>test2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```

Can you suggest a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

With `vertical-align: top`

```css
nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>
      test2
      <ul>
        <li>test2.1</li>
        <li>test2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      test2
      <ul>
        <li>test2.1</li>
        <li>test2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When you hover over a list item in the first level, it affects the list item on the right, because of `display: inline-block`.

Therefore one can use `float: left` and `display: relative` for `<li>` in the first level and `display: absolute` for the `<ul>` inside of the `<li>`.

**Example**

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>
      test2
      <ul>
        <li>test2.1</li>
        <li>test2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      test2
      <ul>
        <li>test2.1</li>
        <li>test2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add position:absolute to your hover element like so

```
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add position:absolute to your hover element like so

```
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's true you just need to add `vertical-align` as `top` to your `inline-block` elements which are `li` tags here.

`display:inline-block` by default aligns their block text to the `baseline` and that's why when user `hover` in above codes it aligns the `text` to the baseline i.e. `vertical-align:baseline` so change that to `vertical-align:top`.

```
nav > ul > li{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /*Just add this as already suggested*/
}
```